# Migrate site from On Prem to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

Is there a way to migrate a SharePoint site from an On Prem environment to SharePoint Online environment using PowerShell? Third-Party apps won't work here

I don't have access to the the On Prem server neither the web but I do have full admin rights for the SharePoint Online. (someone with access to the server could run PowerShell commands there to export the web)

I found [this guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nishants/2015/07/18/using-windows-powershell-cmdlets-for-sharepoint-online-o365spo-migration/) from a Microsoft blog post but as far as I can read there it is only working for migration of Doc Libraries and List, not an entire site or site collection, or am I wrong?

Also, I still don't know if this is SharePoint 2010 or 2013. Trying to find out.

Any help more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You're using SharePoint 2010, If you see:

- The Site Actions button is used to get to all SharePoint 2010's settings.
- Home is a button rather than a link.
- The Quick Launch bar is preset with Libraries, Lists, and Discussions.

You're using SharePoint 2013, If you see:

- There's a ribbon but no app launcher*, and only "SharePoint on the title bar.
- To switch between apps, there is a top menu bar.

However, for SharePoint on premises to SharePoint Online Migration:

- Export the data from the SharePoint 2010 environment using Export-SPWeb.
- Convert the Exported package to the SPO Migration Package using the SharePoint Online Management Shell.
- Upload the SPO Migration Package to your Azure Storage account.
- Submit the Migration Job.

Get step-wise instruction here: http://expert-advice.org/2017/02/sharepoint-2010-on-premises-to-sharepoint-online-office-365-migration/

Here is another informative article i.e.e SharePoint Migration to Online (SPO-O365) from On-Premise SharePoint using Azure API as well as Powershell command: https://migrationspo.blogspot.in/2016/06/sharepoint-migration-to-online-spo-o365_20.html

Hope this helps!